# How to Use url.openstream?

Tags: java, android

When I Run this code I get error on `Input stream in =url.openstream`
Help me. To solve this

I have added **internet** and **write and read permission** in manifest

And  I created a instance of **asyncktask** in on createmethod
I tried `url.openstream` in `doInbackground` but still getting error

Without the asyncktask class I have executed in a Java program. But in Android not working

```
 private class Mine extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"its loading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        try {
            Document doc=Jsoup.connect(addr).get();
            come=doc.title();
            Elements image=doc.getElementsByTag("img");

            for(Element thereimage:image)
            {
                thereimagelink=thereimage.attr("abs:src");
            }
            int indexname = thereimagelink.lastIndexOf("/");

            if(indexname==thereimagelink.length())
            {
                thereimagelink=thereimagelink.substring(1,indexname);
            }
            indexname = thereimagelink.lastIndexOf("/");
            hereimagename=thereimagelink.substring(indexname,thereimagelink.length());







        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+come,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        try {

            URL url=new URL(thereimagelink);
            InputStream in=url.openStream();

            OutputStream out=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(folder+hereimagename));
            for (int b; (b = in.read()) != -1;) {

                out.write(b);

            }
            out.close();

            in.close();

        }catch (IOException e)
        {

        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"its finishd",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the error details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running `url.openStream()` in `onPostExecute()`, which runs on UI thread. Android requires that all network operations should happen in a background thread, so all of that should happen inside `doInBackground()`

Comment: Is that you telling I should put all the code output stream also in do in background?

Comment: If you are opening a network connection and fetching data from the Internet, then yes. Otherwise, you should add the crash log so that we can see what the issue is.

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer so that others can benefit.